# How to handle callbacks and states in MVVM in Android

Tags: java, android, mvvm, architecture, kotlin

I have two questions:

1. How to handle events, like user logged in etc.
   Let's say I have repository and I am calling a Repo.function in my viewModel, and that ViewModel.method is called in my activity, when user presses the button. So, in some time my Repo.method completes and returns 200, and says my user is logged in. The question is, how my android view ( activity / fragment ) should now that it has to navigate? Currently I use EventBus to post and subscribe to such events.
2. How to handle network loading states: default/loading/completed
   Currently I have a separate singleton that has ObservableFields for loaders like val isTokenLoading = ObservableField(false)
   In my viewModel I hold ref to that singleton.isTokenLoading
   My view binds to that viewModel's field
   And in this way I handle UI changes during loading progress

What is the best way to do such things?

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, I would say that the Observer pattern is the way to go (and the one people usually choose). For instance, RxJava fits perfectly in your use case, and you can even use it with LiveData nowadays. You would launch the request on your ViewModel, create an Observable from the response, perform all the operations you need, and do one of the following: subscribe to the final Observable on your view, or subscribe to a LiveData on your view, while updating it through the observable subscription on your ViewModel (I prefer the latter since it keeps the RxJava dependencies out of the view). You have tons of examples online with implementation details on this.

As for your second question, you're already using the Observer pattern (which, again, is the way most people do it), but keeping all loading fields in the same class seems to me like a code smell. It would probably be better to store them on the class that has to deal with them.

Edit: I just came across an article on AndroidPub exploring exactly what you want: https://android.jlelse.eu/android-architecture-communication-between-viewmodel-and-view-ce14805d72bf

Comment: I read the article and I commented there too. With this approach, ViewModel knows everything about View. There is no more-loose-couple between them. I really wonder what the correct approach is.

Comment: @Olkunmustafa how does the ViewModel know about the view? It has no dependencies on it whatsoever :p. Still, nowadays I've been following a unidirectional data flow approach, and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

you should use observer pattern. your repository can return a flow (in kotlin coroutine package) and you can observe this flow in you viewmodel. then you can expose this flow to a live data and observe this live data in your fragment or activity. using live data will help you to avoid memory leak.
for handling network states you can have another live data and post state of network to that. and of course observe it in view if you want.